# Several view controllers in one view controller

Tags: ios, ioc-container, childviewcontroller

I am using a view controller that has several containers in it, and each container has its own view controller.

I want to know if `[topMostViewController removeFromParentViewController]`

will also remove all of its children, so that I don't have any memory leaks, or before that happens i also need to call `removeFromParentViewController` on all the children it has?

Comment: If you're using ARC you shouldn't need to worry about this...is your app using ARC, or MRC (manually memory managed?)

Comment: ARC (some long text to fullfil requirement for minimum message even though 3 letters are enough)

Comment: so you're saying topmost view controller will call viewDidDisappear on its on on all of its children?

Answer (score 0):

`removeFromParentViewController` removes the child from its parent. Any children of the child will remain related to the child. If you've set up your relationships correctly all your children will have `viewWillDisappear`, etc called (*if* you've set up the relationships).

But because you're using ARC, you shouldn't need to care about memory leaks, because the compiler will take care of this for you.

Comment: memory leaks -> uiactivityindicator that wasnt shut off, uianimation that wasnt shut off etc, those will be gone too ?